# Problems with List<Map<String, Object>> streaming

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a List of Map.
This list contains maps that have two fields: date and username (both are string)

For example:

```
data index 0: [0] "datetime" -> "2020-01-31 10:45:33"
[1] "username" -> "myself"

data index 1: [0] "datetime" -> "2020-01-31 10:45:48"
[1] "username" -> "myself"

data index 2: [0] "datetime" -> "2020-01-30 02:45:33"
[1] "username" -> "myself2"

data index 3: [0] "datetime" -> "2020-03-15 10:33:48"
[1] "username" -> "myself2"
```

(The datetime format is yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss)

My goal is to retrieve a list of distinct username with the datetime associated and where the datetime is between now (LocalDateTime.now()) and 5mn before.

So if it's 11:41am, I want to retrieve a list of distinct user + their most recent datetime where this datetime is > 11:36am.
In the example provided, I'll retrieve :

```
"myself" -> "2020-01-31 10:45:48"
"myself2" -> "2020-03-15 10:33:48"
```

I don't know how to filter this list of maps by parsing the string into datetime. Any ideas or advices ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why you want map to store the username and date ? Cant you use a custom object ?

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

This is just to give you an idea how this could be done. There are a few steps involved in this process:

- transform each map to `"myself" -> "2020-01-31 10:45:33"`
- obtain a stream of all intermediate maps
- group by `Map.Entry::getKey`
- select maximum time

```
var pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

var list = List.of(
                Map.of("datetime", "2020-01-31 10:45:33", "username" , "myself"),
                Map.of("datetime","2020-01-31 10:45:48", "username", "myself")
);
```

now let's transform the list to `Map<String, Optional<LocalDateTime>` where 
key is user, and value is maximum time for that user:

```
list.stream()
// creating an intermediate map of user -> time 
        .map(map -> Map.of(map.get("username"), LocalDateTime.parse(map.get("datetime"), pattern)))
// steam containing temporary maps
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(
// group by each user name
                groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
// selecting the maximum/latest time
                        maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String, LocalDateTime>::getValue))
                )
        );
```

Please note that this is just a suggestion to give you an idea. The code has to be adjusted and possible there is a more elegant solution for this. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> myMap = Map.of(
    "2020-01-31 10:45:33", "myself",
    "2020-01-31 10:45:48", "myself",
    "2020-01-30 02:45:33", "myself2",
    "2020-03-15 10:33:48", "myself2"
);
String now = LocalDateTime
    .of(2020,3,1,11,41)
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));

myMap.keySet().stream()
    .filter(key -> key.compareTo(now) < 0)
    .forEach(key -> System.out.println(key +" -> "+myMap.get(key)));
```

Output:

```
2020-01-30 02:45:33 -> myself2
2020-01-31 10:45:33 -> myself
2020-01-31 10:45:48 -> myself
```

You can convert date object to string and compare them. But keep in mind comparing strings is inefficient

- A better solution can be achieved by converting string date to an object of `Date` using `map`.
- You can provide more details about your data and requirements and I will try to help you.

[readable format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1IOg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please find ready to be tested code below.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.maxBy;

public class ListOfMapStreaming {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("myself", "2020-06-11 10:45:33");

        Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("myself", "2020-06-11 18:35:33");

        Map<String,String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
        map3.put("myself2", "2020-01-30 02:45:33");

        Map<String,String> map4 = new HashMap<>();
        map4.put("myself2", "2020-03-15 10:33:48");

        List<Map<String, String>> list1 = Arrays.asList(map1, map2, map3, map4);

        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println(now.toString());

        Predicate<Tuple> onlyWithinLast5Mintues = tuple -> ((now.getTime()- tuple.getDate().getTime()) / (1000*60)) < 5;

        Map<String, Optional<Tuple>> result = list1.stream()
                .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                .map(entry -> convertToTupleObject(entry))
                .filter(onlyWithinLast5Mintues)
                // most recent within last minutes
                .collect(groupingBy(Tuple::getUserName, maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Tuple::getDate))));

        // Now you can convert Date object back to String form if you want :)
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static Tuple convertToTupleObject(Map.Entry<String, String> x) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        try {
            date = dateFormatter.parse(x.getValue());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new Tuple(x.getKey(), date);
    }

    private static class Tuple {
        String userName;
        Date date;

        public Tuple() {
        }

        public Tuple(String userName, Date date) {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.date = date;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }
        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        public void setDate(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Tuple{" +
                    "userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                    ", date=" + date +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Please comment if you have any doubts regarding implementation.